# How to disable eclipse4 built-in keyboard shortcut?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse 4.2 seem has some built-in shortcuts, such as Ctrl+P, Alt+C, Alt+X etc, you can not find them from "Window->preferences->General->Keys". I'd like to re-define these shortcuts, e.g. bind Alt+X to run maven build, but when i press Alt+X, at the bottom right corner of Eclipse, it flashes quickly and my mouse is out of control, i think this is because of shortcut conflict.

Anyone who know how to disable the built-in shortcuts? Thanks.

Edit:
Ctrl+p is only bind to one action.
[image]

When i click Ctrl+p, the bottom right corner show, this message is from from eclipse:

[image]

Well, the above is the good situation--at least you can choose which action to run. for Alt+P, Alt+c you have no chance to choose, eclipse is flipping and you are out of control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of this problem, i import all my keys from Eclipse 3.7 to 4.2, most of them works, however some of them conflict but Eclipse fails to show the conflict shortcuts, Let's say, Ctrl+P, this is print shortcut for eclipse by default, in eclipse 3.7 i bind Ctrl+p to another command, after import, eclipse 4.2 shows just like 3.7(see above), however in fact it still has conflict even though it does not show the conflict. I think this might be an eclipse bug. I'm the one who use shortcut extensively. Hope this help others with migrating shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain there isn't something in your OS or another application that is handling those keyboard triggers? If you assign a keyboard shortcut in Eclipse's Preferences, it will indicate when there is a conflict; if you don't see that, then it's not an Eclipse shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however it is not like what you said, I think if you are using eclipse 4, just try to bind say Alt+C to another action, and then use it, you can see the conflict.

Comment: In my standard Eclipse 4.2 installation, there is nothing bound to Alt+C. I was able to bind a command to it and it works just fine. Eclipse doesn't appear to use Alt+C unless you configure it to, and it doesn't utilize *any* keyboard shortcuts that aren't user-configurable that I know of; Again, really sounds like your scenario is some other app or OS function grabbing those shortcuts. Can you post a picture of what happens when you try Alt+C? What happens if you use Alt+C in another app?

Comment: Like I said, "standard" Eclipse doesn't bind any action to Alt+C (or Alt+X as far as I can tell). If it did, they'd be listed in the *Keys* preferences. Since you have Easy Shell installed, perhaps you have installed some other third-party plugin that is using those shortcuts. Or, there is some other app on your system that is doing it.

Comment: Hi Riz, i found the root cause, thanks for giving me your ideas and your patience.